# CF8 and Salesforce REST API - updating records

Tags: coldfusion, salesforce

I'm trying to do integration with Salesforce using their REST API and CF8.
I got the OAuth bit working, getting data etc but now I'm trying to update some records in Contact table.

First I tought about doing it the "proper" way as their [docs say](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_update_fields.htm) -

> Update a record using HTTP PATCH.

But CFHTTP doesn't support PATCH method.

So then I tried running a SOQL query:

```
UPDATE Contact SET MailingStreet = 'Blah Blah' WHERE Id = '003A000000Zp4ObIAJ'
```

but here I'm getting

> {"message":"unexpected token: UPDATE","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create your own PATCH method if your client supports it, but there is an easier way. From the [Force.com REST API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/dome_sobject_create.htm?SearchType=Stem):

> If you use an HTTP library that doesn't allow overriding or setting an
>   arbitrary HTTP method name, you can send a POST request and provide an
>   override to the HTTP method via the query string parameter
>   _HttpMethod. In the PATCH example, you can replace the PostMethod line
>   with one that doesn't use override:

```
PostMethod m = new PostMethod(url + "?_HttpMethod=PATCH");
```

Answer (score 2):

In CF9 CFScript, using the method that Paddyslacker already suggested for adding _HttpMethod=PATCH to the URL:

```
private boolean function patchObject(required string sfid, required string type, required struct obj) {
    local.url = variables.salesforceInstance & '/services/data/v' & variables.apiVersion &'/sobjects/' & arguments.type & '/' & arguments.sfid &'?_HttpMethod=PATCH';
    local.http = new Http(url=local.url,method='post');
    //... convert obj to a json string, add to local.http ...
    local.httpSendResult = local.http.send().getPrefix();
}
```

We have a CF9 CFC that we wrote that wraps most of the REST API that we will be open sourcing soon. I'll come back and link to it when we do.

Comment: Hi Dan, did you guys ever open source your CFC?

Comment: Not the full thing, but we do have a trimmed down version in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/danwatt/1827874